# Antialiasing PNG resize in Qt?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface

In a PyQt based GUI program, I'm drawing a few PNG file as QPixmap after resize. So here is basically what happens:

```
bitmap = QPixmap( "foo.png" )
bitmap.scaleToHeight(38) # original is larger than this
scene.addItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem(bitmap)) # Add to graphics scene
```

The problem is: afterwards, the bitmap is rather ugly. Is there a way to do this in a antialiasing way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qpixmap.html#scaledToHeight).

```
bitmap = bitmap.scaledToHeight(38, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
```